# Moonlight/Silverlight - is it still working

Tags: moonlight

I know that this question (how open Silverlight/Moonlight web pages in Ubuntu?) has been asked million of times, but it seems that no one of this solutions works for me.
Even if I added legacy repositories, I'm still unable to install Moonlight plugin for Firefox.

Is there any way to resolve it or do I need to abandon Ubuntu and install Open Suse (which is natively supported by Novell Moonlight)?

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to install"? You'll need to be a lot more specific than that ;-)

Answer (score 3):

“We have abandoned Moonlight.

[image]

Silverlight has not gained much adoption on the web, so it did not become the must-have technology that I thought would have to become. And Microsoft added artificial restrictions to Silverlight that made it useless for desktop programming.“ - **Xamarin**

[image]

You can download this [novell-moonlight-39903-x86_64.xpi](http://www.4shared.com/file/D2uVB5uQ/novell-moonlight-39903-x86_64.htm) file,
then right click and open with Firefox. 
This will install moonlight. Click install.
That's it..

Comment: Not valid anymore as the project has been abandoned and had older version of silverlight. As now there is [Pipelight](http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-08/pipelight-using-silverlight-in-linux-browsers.html) for the latest silverlight you need.

Answer (score 1):

The below linked help me to install pipelight instead of moonlight. Charts are working fine now.

http://www.itworld.com/software/414056/install-silverlight-alternative-pipelight-ubuntu-1404

Comment: I agree that Pipelight is the way to go! Before Google Chrome added DRM code to their HTML5 implementation, the only option for watching Netflix on Linux was by using Pipelight.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox checks whether a plug-in is computable with the current version of Firefox, and since there is no development with the moonlight plug-in it doesn't report that it is computable with the current version of Firefox. I found a add-on to disable the check [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkcompatibility/). after installing that you can enable or install moonlight.