# How to install moonlight in Ubuntu 12.0.4?

Tags: 12.04, installation, moonlight

I tried to open this [link](https://coxy7ezff6.database.windows.net/) in Ubuntu 12.0.4. but it suggested to install silverlight.

I searched in Google for this, finally I got Ubuntu not supported to SilverLight, so we need to install MoonLight.

For this, I run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

after installing, I refresh the above page. Still it's not working.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Did you restart the browser, or just refresh the page? Usually when installing plugins you need to close Firefox and reopen it for them to take hold.

Comment: @JezW already I did.

Comment: You can try this out, [Moonlight/Silverlight - is it still working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318284/moonlight-silverlight-is-it-still-working/318448#318448)

Comment: @Shaharil Ahmad I downloaded `novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-x86_64.xpi` from your link. and I open `mozilla firefox` and drag the file into `Firefox`.successfully installed plug-in and I enabled Plug-in.I reopen `Firefox` and open the above link(what I mention in question).earlier it shows some image with `Install silverLight`.but after install plug-in,it showing progress like `1%..20%..80%`.after it's not showing anything(it showing blank page).
How can I fix this.

Comment: Not valid anymore as the project has been abandoned and had older version of silverlight. As now there is [Pipelight](http://fds-team.de/cms/articles/2013-08/pipelight-using-silverlight-in-linux-browsers.html) for the latest silverlight you need.